# Select Date delivers wrong results

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to return some results from my database where the column date_order is 1970 but the query also returns dates from 2014 and 2015. I have tried a couple query's but its all the same.

My table

- `accession_id (INT),`
- `date_order(DATE) DEFAULT '0000-00-00',`
- `date_billed(DATE) DEFAULT '0000-00-00',`
- `date_paid(DATE) DEFAULT   '0000-00-00'`

My Query's:

1. `SELECT DISTINCT(accession_id), date_order, date_billed, date_paid FROM billing WHERE date(date_order) = '1970-01-01'  AND accession_id BETWEEN '206070' AND '296715' OR '402603' AND '411626';`
2. `SELECT DISTINCT(accession_id), date_order, date_billed, date_paid FROM billing WHERE date_order = '1970-01-01'  AND accession_id BETWEEN '206070' AND '296715' OR '402603' AND '411626';`
3. `SELECT DISTINCT(accession_id), date_order, date_billed, date_paid FROM billing WHERE date_order LIKE '%1970%'  AND accession_id BETWEEN '206070' AND '296715' OR '402603' AND '411626';`

Comment: I`m guessing you need parantheses  because of operator precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your BETWEEN after the first set of dates, and use parenthesis.  Like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(accession_id), date_order, date_billed, date_paid FROM billing WHERE date(date_order) = '1970-01-01' AND 
(
  accession_id BETWEEN '206070' AND '296715'
  OR
  accession_id BETWEEN '402603' AND '411626'
);
```

As it stands now, those numbers are evaluating to true, and they are ORed in, so you will get all the results.